# Connecting charged capacitor to uncharged capacitor by conducting wire

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

The capacitor A has a charge $q$ on it whereas capacitor $B$ is uncharged.The charge appearing on capacitor B a long time after the switch is closed is found to be zero still.Why?

[image]

Comment: It is obvious that zero charge should flow;as the right plate of the right capacitor is initially isolated and uncharged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact can be mathematically proved.

*Initially charge on the right plate of capacitor A is $-q$ and that on the left of capacitor $B$ is zero.The electric field inside the two capacitors and energy stored in them are:*

> $$E_A=\frac{q}{A\epsilon_o}$$ 
>   $$U_A=(1/2)\epsilon_o{E_A}^2(Ad)=\frac{q^2d}{2\epsilon_oA}$$ $$E_B=0$$
>   $$U_B=0$$

Let charge $q'$ moves from right plate of A to the left plate of B when switch S is closed.By charge conservation,charge remaining on right plate of A is $-q-q'$.

*New electric fields and potential energies are:*

> $$E_A=\frac{q}{2A\epsilon_o}-\frac{-q-q'}{2A\epsilon_o}$$ 
>   $$U_A=(1/2)\epsilon_o{E_A}^2(Ad)=\frac{q^2d}{2\epsilon_oA}(1+\frac{q'}{2q})^2$$ 
>   $$E_B=\frac{q'}{2A\epsilon_o}$$
>   $$U_B=\frac{q'^2d}{8A\epsilon_o}$$

Use the energy conservation $U_A+U_B=U'_A+U'_B$ to get $q'=0$[possible] or $q'=2q$[not possible].

Comment: This are static arguments for a dynamic situation. Hence, the question as well as the answer are wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Cheers. :-) @mikuszefski

Comment: Why do you think energy conservation should hold like this? Why you assumed that heat lost during rearrangement shall be zero?